# Deleting an array element in C

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote the following program to delete an array element entered by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int j, i, a[100], n, key, l;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the number of elements:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter the elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    printf("\nEnter the element to delete:");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    l = n;  //Length of the array
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (a[i] == key) {
           for (j = i; j < l; j++)
               a[j] = a[j + 1];
           l--;    //Decreasing the length of the array
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe new array is \n");
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
     getch();
}
```

It works fine for most inputs but when the input is something like: `1 2 2 3 5` (here `2` repeats consecutively) and the element to be deleted is `2`, the output is `1 2 3 5`.

How can I modify the program such that all instances of the entered element is removed?

Comment: is this homework or for a coding test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After l-- put i-- too as shown below

```
if(a[i]==key)
  {
   for(j=i;j<l;j++)
    a[j]=a[j+1];
   l--;    //Decreasing the length of the array
   i--;    //check again from same index i
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the blast from the past, but wont a[j]= a[j+1} fail in the case when j is pointing to the last element in the array

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the order of the elements in the array, you can move the last element of the array into the newly formed gap (cunningly reducing the length of the array by one). This can be vastly more efficient than shunting the elements down: in computer science term this makes deleting an element O(1) rather than O(N).

```
a[i] = a[--l];
```

If your i index is looping over the array, you'll want to loop over this element again:

```
a[i--] = a[--l];
```

For example, to remove all elements '3' from an array of length 'l':

```
for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    if (a[i] == 3) {
        a[i--] = a[--l];
    }
}
```

If you *do* care about the order of the elements in the array, it's most efficient to use memmove rather than move elements by hand. It's designed to be used where the source and destination memory overlap.

```
memmove(a + i, a + i + 1, sizeof(a[0]) * (l - i - 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Other posters have given you 2 solutions ... I think understanding why it happens is good too :)

Let's take your example `1, 2, 2, 3, 5` and follow the code line by line

```
i = 0;             /* first time through the loop; i "points" to 1 */
if (a[i] == 2) ... /* nope; next loop */
i = 1;
if (a[1] == 2) ... /* yes! let's go inside the if */
                   /* move all elements back
                   ** and "decrease" array length */
                   /* array is now 1, 2, 3, 5 */
                   /* next loop */
i = 2;
if (a[i] == 2) ... /* nope; OH! Wait ...
                   ** a[1] is the new 2 and it wasn't checked */
```

Comment: +1: I was very confused until I've seen your post. The big thrick is to decrement the loop counter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change "if" to "while":

```
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        while (i<l && a[i]==key)
        {
            for(j=i;j<l;j++)
                a[j]=a[j+1];
            l--;    //Decreasing the length of the array
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid my trick was buggy - deleting the last element could loop indefinitely (depending on the value of a[l], which is beyond the array). Addrd i<l to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

use a new array.

```
int array[l];
int k=0;
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
{
 if(a[i]!=key)
 {
  array[k]=a[i];
  k++;
 }

}
```

Comment: just pay attention to the size of the array. i didn't check it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
int size;
int array[20];
int delete_pos;
int i;

printf("Enter the Size of the Array :");
scanf("%d",&size);


for(i=0;i<=size-1;i++){                                //no of elements taken are 1 less than size of the array asked.
    printf("\nEnter the element[%d] :",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}

printf("\nEnter the Position of the array to be deleted :");
scanf("%d",&delete_pos);


for(i=delete_pos-1;i<=size;i++){                    //every element of the array is replaced by array on next position.
    array[i]=array[i+1];}

size=size-1;                                       // Reducing the size of the array as one element is deleted.
printf("Your new array is \n");
for(i=0;i<=size-1;i++){                            //printing the entire new array.
    printf("%d ",array[i]);

}
printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer.@Dhruv Aditya Mittal

Comment: First it will ask the size of the array and later it will ask the elements to be written in the array.After taking the elements it will ask which array is to be deleted from the array.The final output will print the remaining elements in the array i.e new array. @RohitPoudel

Answer (score 0):

Your method with 2 nested `for` loops is too complicated. You can simple scan the array with an index `i` and copy all elements different from `key` with a different index `len`. The resulting array length is the final value of `len`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[100];
    int i, n, key, len;

    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < 0 || n > 100) {
        printf("invalid number of elements\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nEnter the elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\nEnter the element to delete: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &key) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = len = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] != key)
           a[len++] = a[i];
    }

    printf("\nThe new array is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)` and it is considered good style to return `0` for success.
- always test the return value of `scanf()`. This prevents many bugs and undefined behavior for invalid input. It also saves a lot of time looking in the wrong places when input was just invalid.
- avoid naming a variable `l` as it looks too close to `1` in many fixed pitch fonts.
- always terminate the program output with a newline.